# Custom font in universal app

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal, uifont, italic

Hi guys i am using a custom font in universal application and it is working good on iPhone but on iPad it is showing in *Italic*. please help me[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you including both the italic and normal fonts on separate files? sometimes the iPhone replaces one of the fonts with another from the same family.

Comment: thanx for reply jano, No i have included only mono

Comment: there is same file in both resources and that is not italic,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved i was using xcode 3.2.5 with sdk4.1 and now when i updated my xcode to xcode 4.2 and iOS sdk 5.0 then this problem was solved automatically. Xcode 4.2 is really awesome